Spark Streaming not executing ForEach block in Continuous mode
I am using spark streaming to read data from a kafka broker and am trying to test it out with continuous mode but have been finding that I cannot get a forEach operation to execute. I have it working with micro batches using this code and am able to log print statements to the executors and trace through everything.
query = df\
       .writeStream\
       .outputMode('update')\
       .format('console') \
       .trigger(processingTime= '2 seconds')\
       .foreach(myFunc)\
       .start()

Additionally when switching to continuous mode, I can see that the data is correctly processed and written to the sink if I do not use a forEach operation.
query = df\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('update')\
        .format('console') \
        .trigger(continuous= '2 seconds')\
        .start()

I  want to be able to see that myFunc is being executed. When I log the spark executor I do not see any print statements, etc in continuous mode. Logging the executor shows
NFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-85b5ed60-d0b8-413c-8e4e-6ea134f36e2b-695052740-executor-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-85b5ed60-d0b8-413c-8e4e-6ea134f36e2b-695052740-executor] Seeking to latest offset of partition topic1-0
24/05/01 18:37:08 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-85b5ed60-d0b8-413c-8e4e-6ea134f36e2b-695052740-executor-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-85b5ed60-d0b8-413c-8e4e-6ea134f36e2b-695052740-executor] Resetting offset for partition topic1-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=112974, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka-controller-0.kafka-controller-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=70}}.
24/05/01 18:37:08 WARN KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
24/05/01 18:37:08 INFO KafkaConsumer: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-85b5ed60-d0b8-413c-8e4e-6ea134f36e2b-695052740-executor-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-85b5ed60-d0b8-413c-8e4e-6ea134f36e2b-

which continues repeating in some form. Additionally the spark history server shows no tasks being worked on or completed when calling the forEach block.
I am running spark 3.5.0 in cluster mode and am adding the jar org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.0
